# Fixing mod_rewrite rule in Apache to apply only to one domain

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I currently have

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ^ezrahub.com/index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Which is fine if I have a single site, but I didn't realize this would mess up every other domain on my server (yikes!.

I basically only want to rewrite `http://ezrahub.com/index.php/$1` to remove the `index.php` and create a clean URL on that domain and not show the index.php... apologies for the noob question.. how do I need to approach this?

Comment: You should have separate `<VirtualHost>` entries for each domain on your server, and typically, none of them should be sharing directories. Something is very strange about your setup. Can you describe it in much more detail?

Comment: You're right, they shouldn't share directories, but since these are not really production level sites and are used simple for experimentation two sites do share the same directory... (which creates problems, as I realize)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I agree with Michael Hamptons response, here's a quick fix to do what you want:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ezrahub.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ^ezrahub.com/index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

As you see, I added the condition that the Host header be ezrahub.com, in addittion to requiring that the file is nonexistent.

Kudos to you for using your actual hostname, it makes it  a lot easier to help!

Comment: That's what I needed. Also worth noting that that code isn't actually correct, the rewriterule should be `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: You're completely right about the RewriteRule, sorry I missed that - I was just focusing on the conditions!